# How do I layout relative positioned 'li' like a paragraph with line breaks?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html-lists, nav

heres my jsfiddle, please take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/63pNN/

I am having trouble formatting this 'ul'.  Its meant for a wordpress so more 'li' elements will be added.  The 'li' elements need to be 'position:relative;' so that when they go from 'display:none' to 'display:inline', with a jquery drop-down function, the 'div' will change in height to accommodate.

I want the list to appear like this:

Home Item1 Item2 Item3

ItemA ItemB ItemC ItemD ItemE ItemF

ItemX ItemY ItemZ

Should I use a table for this?
How do I get these elements to appear this way?
I've tried left floating the 'ul'.

The list will work like a dropdown menu, so that when Item2 > ItemC is selected, the list should appear like this:

Home Item1 **Item2** Item3

**ItemC** ItemD

ItemY

Also if you have any ideas of how to make only one sibling appear at a time, on click, or toggle, please let me know.  I have any idea that the parent should adopt a class that means its 'selected', and then add a class to its children so they appear.  And then the parent should lose its 'selected' class when one of its siblings are clicked.  But im having trouble getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
li {
   float: left;
}
```

or:

```
li {
   display: inline;
}
```

Comment: i really need it to be relative to its siblings **only** and _not_ its parent